Xcode could not build modules
im veryy new to mobile development, and i tried implementing firebase. however, i've been getting issues when building my project. a bunch of modules won't build:
failing modules
and this is an example of what the error log looks like:
errors
this is what my Podfile looks like right now:
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '13.4'
prepare_react_native_project!

# Include ReactCommon dependencies
pod 'ReactCommon', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'
pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon'

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'CampusWatch' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  # Apply modular headers only to specific Firebase-related pods
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreInternal', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true

  target 'CampusWatchTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer, config[:reactNativePath])

    # Optionally, handle ReactCommon modulemap conflicts
    # system("rm -rf Pods/Target\\ Support\\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.modulemap")
  end
end

i tried asking chatgpt and it was telling me to change my header search paths and library search paths to be like this for both the project and project target:
search path example
it also suggested that i add frameworks to the build phases under "link binary with libraries" but i didn't see any changes
if anyone can help out, i'd appreciate it!

Your errors screenshot says permission error, and for your module failing issue is you do not have your node_modules installed.
try running the command with sudo.
And make sure you have node_modules folder in place and also you have done pod installation (i.e go to cd /ios and run pod install)
